# Is there a test program for Scala.g4 in antlr4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Refer to: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4
Under Java8, there is a test.java program that illustrates how to use the Java8Lexer, Java8Parser class generated by Java8.g4. However, in scala there is no such test program.

So just wondering can anyone show me a test program? Or if test.java can be directly used in scala without too much modification?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't recommend using the Scala.g4 grammar: it is full of errors.

Comment: True, I actually can solve what I want by using Java8.g4. I can parse scala as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bart Kiers mentioned above, I found scala.g4 grammer full or error too. I solved my problem by just using Java8.g4 to parse scala program. Luckily everything works perfect! But just be careful when using the given test.java program, don't forget to modify the "getFilenames_" function as it looks for .java file by default. Modify it to accept .scala file.